# Python - Regular Expression replace all non alpha-numerics EXCEPT periods/decimal points?

Tags: python, regex

So I needed to take out all the non-alpha numeric characters out of a string so i did this:

```
import re
re.sub(r'\W+', '', "He&y wha*t i%%s 4.6 plu^s 6.4?")
```

And it becomes:

```
"Heywhatis46plus46"
```

Now how do I do that, but without erasing any decimal points? (I know it seems like I need spaces and punctuation also, but all I need is the periods)
So that it becomes:

```
"Heywhatis4.6plus4.6"
```

Comment: What should happen to `_`? That's a `\w` character.

Comment: @user2357112 I guess that stays then if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print re.sub(r'[^\w.]+', '', "He&y wha*t i%%s 4.6 plu^s 6.4?")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

print re.sub('([^\w.]|(?<!\d)\.(?!\d))+',
             '',
             "He&y wh...a*t i%%s 4.6 plu^s 6.4?")
```

result

```
Heywhatis4.6plus6.4
```